# Create thumbnail for large .psd and .tiff files in cocoa (objective-c)

Tags: objective-c, applescript, thumbnails, tiff, psd

I am developing an OSX application dealing with very large images (500 MB to + 1.0 GB). My application needs to load the images (.psd & .tif) and allows the user to sort the images, rate the images and etc.

I would like to load a small thumbnail of the image. So here is what I am struggling with:

I have tried to generate the thumbnail in three different ways and the fastest has been about 17 second for generating each thumbnail.

I am looking for recommendations on how to decrease the thumbnail generation time. Do you guys know a library that I could use? Maybe another way to speed this up.

Attempts:

1. I used CGImage's thumbnail generation method   `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex`   to generate the image.
2. I used embedding AppleScript in my Cocoa and used the following command `do shell script (\"/usr/bin/qlmanage -t -s640 \" & quoted form of file_Path & space & \" -o \" & quoted form of save_path`
3. I used grabbing the thumbnail from image preview using `QLThumbnailImageCreate`

both 1 & 2 been around 17 second generation time for each image. 3 returns the blank image. I think it has to do with the fact that preview needs to load it.

I also tried using GCD (Grand Central dispatch) to speed things up too, however it seems due to the disk read bottleneck, the processes are always in serial and do not get executed in paralel. So multi-threading using different queues didn't help (used dispatch_async).

Its worth mentioning that all these images exist on an external hard drive which my application will be reading. The idea is to do this without needing to move the files.

Again i am using Objective-C and developing this of OSX 10.8. I am hoping maybe there is a C++ / C library or something faster than the three options I found my self.

Any help is greatly appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you get the same timings when loading from the local disk. I ask because it may not be the loading via which ever method you use but where you are loading from. I have this problem with a commercial app that loads large thumbnails of thousands of images. But if I load them from a share point it can take 20mins for say 1500 images. Where as copying the files first to my local drive ( couple of minutes ) it can then take about 40seconds to build all the thumbs.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a preview/thumbnail embedded in the file, you can try to create the CGImageSource with a mapped file (so only the bytes that are really necessary for generating the thumbnail will be read from the disk):

```
NSURL* inURL = ... // The URL for your PSD or TIFF file

// Create an NSData object that copies only the required bytes to memory:
NSDataReadingOptions dataReadingOptions = NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe;
NSData* data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:inURL options:dataReadingOptions error:nil];

// Create a CGImageSourceRef that do not cache the decompressed result:
NSDictionary* sourcOptions =
        @{(id)kCGImageSourceShouldCache: (id)kCFBooleanFalse,
          (id)kCGImageSourceTypeIdentifierHint: (id)typeName
        };
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((CFDataRef)data,(CFDictionaryRef)sourceOptions);

// Create a thumbnail without caching the decompressed result:
NSDictionary* thumbOptions = @{(id)kCGImageSourceShouldCache: (id)kCFBooleanFalse,
  (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailWithTransform: (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
  (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageIfAbsent:  (id)kCFBooleanTrue,
  (id)kCGImageSourceCreateThumbnailFromImageAlways: (id)kCFBooleanFalse,
  (id)kCGImageSourceThumbnailMaxPixelSize:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:kIMBMaxThumbnailSize]};

result = CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(source,0,(CFDictionaryRef)options);

// Clean up
CFRelease(source);
[data release];

// Return the result (autoreleased):
return [NSMakeCollectable(result) autorelease];
```